# Using Facebook and other sites haram

Tags: halal-haram

Assalam u Alaikum

My question is that is it halal to use sites such as facebook and google as they are invented by jews and tge real problem is most of them are illuminati, freemasonry members amd joining them is haram so what will be the ruling

Also i dont use these sites myself but my family members and the institute i study in have facebook pages

So what should i do

ALLAH HAFIZ

Comment: Waallaikum sallam, welcome to Islam stack exchange where you can increase yourself in knowledge and contribute to the development of Islam, you can visit [ask] for more information.

Comment: They is nothing wrong by using those site as far as you did it for the sake of Allah and developing deen wasalamu alaikum